# In 3 layer MLP, why should the input to hidden weights be random?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

For Example for 3-1-1 layer if the weights are initialized equally the MLP might not learn well. But why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one neuron in the hidden layer, it doesn't matter. But, imagine a network with two neurons in the hidden layer. If they have the same weights for their input, than both neurons would always have the exact same activation, there is no additional information by having a second neuron. And in the backpropagation step, those weights would change by an equal amount. Hence, in every iteration, those hidden neurons have the same activation.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a typo in your question title. I'm guessing that you mean why should the *weights* of hidden layer be random.  For the example network you indicate (3-1-1), it won't matter because you only have a single unit in the hidden layer. However, if you had multiple units in the hidden layer of a fully connected network (e.g., 3-2-1) you should randomize the weights because otherwise, all of the weights to the hidden layer will be updated *identically*.  That is not what you want because each hidden layer unit would be producing the same hyperplane, which is no different than just having a single unit in that layer.